# prevent XSS attack on JSTL & JSP scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, validation, jstl, xss

[image]

I have a web application which accept html template from my users to render a specific page as they like to see it. I made some conventions for rendering dynamic contents for them like using ${news} for rendering the latest news:

I said them for see the latest news put the ${news} tag between your html tags like this:

```
<div style="desiredStyle">
    <forEach varStatus="item" items=${news} >
        <div>
            <p>${item.title}</p>
            <p>${item.content}</p>
        </div>
    </forEach>
</div>
```

anyways I want to prevent them from using any other JSTL or JSP tag other than my defined params ex: `${news}` to prevent data leak and XSS attack.

The question is how can I allow usage of html tags and javascript codes in my `<textarea>` input element and prevent malicious JSTL and JSP Scriptlet codes?

Is there any library for these purposes?